# When editor/collaborator deletes a Google form response--some notification?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

If a response is deleted manually in a Google form, is any flag/notice available to apps-script so that appropriate actions can be scripted for dealing with the corresponding row in the linked sheet?  This is desired so that the sheet can be kept in synch with the form responses, or the form response can be re-submitted programmatically from the sheet row, if the response was improperly deleted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no delete response event trigger available for both [Google Sheets events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events) and [Google Forms events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events).

One workaround that you may do is to create an `onOpen()` [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) in your linked Google Sheets using Apps Script that will check if the Google Forms responses count using [Form.getResponses()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getresponses) matches the available responses in your sheet whenever you open the linked Google Sheets.

**Sample Apps Script:**

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var form = FormApp.openById('Forms file id here');
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  
  var responseSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  
  //Get number of responses saved in the sheet (Subtract 1 for the header row);
  var sheetResponses = responseSheet.getLastRow() - 1;
  
  Logger.log(formResponses.length);
  Logger.log(sheetResponses);
  
  if (formResponses.length != sheetResponses){
    
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 

    var result = ui.alert(
      'Warning',
      'Responses did not match.',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK);

    // Sync responses here
  }

}
```

**Sample Forms Responses:**
[image]

**Sample Output:** (when you open your linked Google Sheets)
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for taking time to confirm this.  I indeed had thought to add that count check to my form submit trigger (because this is a workflow form) as a subroutine and email if a discrepancy.  Just wanted to be sure there wasn't something more direct.